# Cron job still running after deletion from cron.hourly

Tags: centos, cron

I installed yum-cron on my CentOS 7 VM, but decided I did not need it to run hourly. So I tried to rename, and later completely remove, `/etc/cron.hourly/0yum-hourly` and `/etc/yum/yum-cron-hourly.conf`. However, for weeks now I've been getting the following emails hourly:

```
/etc/cron.hourly/0yum-hourly.cron.old:

Error reading config file: /etc/yum/yum-cron-hourly.conf
```

Except I have guaranteed that the file `/etc/cron.hourly/0yum-hourly.cron.old` no longer exists, in any form or by any name; the file has been deleted. I have restarted the `crond` and `yum-cron` services, yet the problem persists. Why (or perhaps more importantly, how) does cron keep insisting on running a job that no longer exists?

Answer (score 1):

You did not delete `0yum-hourly.cron`; you renamed it to an `.old` file that is still being executed.

Any scripts under `/etc/cron.hourly` will be executed hourly, so you have to remove the file or move it to a backup directory for `cron` to stop executing it.

Comment: From my original post: 

"I have guaranteed that the file /etc/cron.hourly/0yum-hourly.cron.old no longer exists; the only places any 0yum* file exists is in cron.daily, and my home directory."

The file has been deleted.

Comment: The evidence suggests otherwise. Did you restart cron *AFTER* deleting this file? What do your logs say?

Answer (score 0):

You said that you deleted (or in the case of the latter, possibly renamed) the files:

```
0yum-hourly.cron.old 
yum-cron-hourly.conf
```

Your error message says:

```
/etc/cron.hourly/0yum-hourly.cron.old:
Error reading config file: /etc/yum/yum-cron-hourly.conf
```

From what I can surmise, the `yum-cron` service is still running but the `conf` file either doesn't exist or is named something else.

You will either need to stop the service or restore `/etc/yum/yum-cron-hourly.conf`. If you don't need `yum-cron` anymore then you can just uninstall it after stopping the service.